# Как замаскировать номера счетов в тексте файла?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Метод должен читать файл и маскировать номера счетов. Должны быть видны только первые 4 и последние 4 цифры (1234 **** **** 5678). Метод должен содержать регулярное выражение для поиска счета. Как реализовать этот метод так, чтоб он вернул текст с маскированными номерами счетов?

```
File file = new File(
                "data.txt");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d){4}\\s(\\d){4}\\s(\\d){4}\\s(\\d){4}\\b+");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                while (m.find()) {
                    char[] textCharMass = line.substring(m.start(), m.end()).toCharArray();
                    char[] encryptedText = new char[textCharMass.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < textCharMass.length; i++) {
                        if (i > 4 && i < 14 && textCharMass[i] != ' ') {
                            encryptedText[i] = (char) 42;
                        } else {
                            encryptedText[i] = textCharMass[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Шифрование это гораздо сложнее и больше. Вам же просто ХХХХ нужно подставить?

Comment: Вообщем да. Мне нужно, чтобы в тексте, где встречаются комбинации 1234 4356 2389 5678 (пример), которые могут быть более одного раза, произвести замену на 1234 **** **** 5678 и вернуть этот текст.

Comment: Приведите однозначные примеры текстов и что в них заменить в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Comment: Пример: Вчера вечером со счета номер 4301 0234 2145 2140 был совершен перевод на счет 5042 2012 0532 2043 в размере ${payment_amount} рублей. Вывод: Вчера вечером со счета номер 4301 **** **** 2140 был совершен перевод на счет 5042 **** **** 2043 в размере ${payment_amount} рублей. Номер счета ищется по регулярному выражению в условии.

Comment: @Dmitriy обновил ответ и шаблон, можно проверить по ссылке: https://regex101.com/r/8elJV1/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD: Изменены группы захвата в позитивных просмотрах назад и вперед на не захватываемые. В связи с этой проблемой при замене не правильно подставлялись данные

Автоматически сформированный код на regex101.com

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(?<=(?:[^\\d]|^))(\\d{4}[ \\t])(?:\\d{4}[ \\t]){2}(\\d{4})(?=(?:[^\\d]|$))";
final String string = "1234 1234 1234 1234\n"
     + "1234 5678 9101 1121\n"
     + "1234 84848 5454 4888\n"
     + "1111 2222 5555 4444\n"
     + "1111 2222 5555 44444\n"
     + "11111 2222 5555 4444\n"
     + "asa1111 2222 5555 4444dasda";
final String subst = "$1**** **** $2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

Подробнее о регулярном выражении:

```
(?<=(?:[^\d]|^))(\d{4}[ \t])(?:\d{4}[ \t]){2}(\d{4})(?=(?:[^\d]|$))
```

Где `(?<=(?:[^\d]|^))` позитивный просмотр назад, и если у нас идет не цифра или начало строки перед группой, то захватываем.
Первая группа захвата `(\d{4}[ \t])` 4 идущие подряд цифры, после них пробел или табуляция
Не захватываемая группа `(?:\d{4}[ \t]){2}` 4 идущие подряд цифры, после них пробел или табуляция, группа повторяется 2 раза
Вторая группа захвата `(\d{4})` 4 цифры идущие подряд
Далее позитивный просмотр вперед, что у нас нет дальше цифр или это конец строки `(?=(?:[^\d]|$))`

В замене возвращаем первую и вторую захваченные группы, а между ними символы
`$1**** **** $2`

Посмотреть пример можно тут: https://regex101.com/r/8elJV1/2

Comment: По комментарию ТСа мне показалось, что может быть не только 4 подряд 4значных числа через пробелы, но и 8, 16 и т.п., а в них надо заменить 6, 14 4значных чисел, а не только 2 -- *"которые могут быть более одного раза"*

Comment: @dIm0n, тоже об этом думал, но делал по примеру в комментариях, но видел что уже запросил уточнение у автора, если данный способ не то что нужно, то отредактирую/удалю. По поводу более одного раза, мною было понято что в одной строке может быть более одного счета...

Comment: Это то, что нужно, спасибо.